# ethereum couldn't connect to a node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I keep getting this message with any version of ethereum I download and open.

I tried to run as administrator but same issue.

other questions on SO have different errors.

[image]

when I check the path `C:\gopath` It doesn't exist.